# Jenkins Pipeline job; proper quoting for slackSend step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, slack

This is probably 100% user error, but I can't get a pipeline job to use a variable as the channel name in a slackSend step.

This uses both the [Slack plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin) and the [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin). I'm trying to use `BUILD_USER_FIRST_NAME` to identify which channel to Slack back to (ie, the one starting the build should be the one to get the message).

Got halfway there with [this article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226287607-How-to-use-Build-User-Vars-Plugin-with-Pipeline) on how to use the build user plugin in a pipeline job, but substituting the variable is tripping me up.

The relevant part of the job looks like this;

```
stage ('message') {

    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {

        sh "printf '%s' ${BUILD_USER_FIRST_NAME} > name.txt"

    }

    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'name.txt'
    name = readFile('name.txt')
    echo "name is $name" //works fine, I get Alex

    if ( "$output" != null ) {
        slackSend (channel: '@$name', color: '#36A64F', message: "Job succeeded")
    } else {
        slackSend (channel: '@$name', color: '#36A64F', message: "Job failed")
    }

}
```

I've tried the following in place of the channel bit, all have failed with indeterminate `Slack post may have failed. Response: Invalid channel specified` errors.

```
channel: '@${name}',
channel: '@" + ${name} + "',
channel: '@"${name}"',
```

Expected output is that it would resolve to `channel: '@Alex',`

What's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Groovy you have to use double quotes to get string interpolation:

```
    if ( "$output" != null ) {
        slackSend (channel: "@${name}", color: '#36A64F', message: "Job succeeded")
    } else {
        slackSend (channel: "@${name}", color: '#36A64F', message: "Job failed")
    }
```

You can also probably do something like this to avoid it entirely and have less duplication:

```
name = '@' + readFile('name.txt')

slackSend (channel: name //etc.
```